# Visit Website script in Java, perl, or vbs

Tags: java, perl, scripting, vbscript

Hello I am new into programming , I want make a script in java or vsb that visits a google , logs in and makes a search. I've done my homework and all I found is some PHP. thank you very much I just want to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're trying to do is called web scraping or "headless web browsing". There're a number of libraries that can perform this for you, for instance [htmlunit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HtmlUnit) or httpunit in Java. You can also look at the Q&A about [web scraping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping).

Comment: Thank you man! , this help me to understand better what I am doing.